# Errors when uploading a huge database from few csv

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am uploading a huge csv file, which I had to split because it was too large to upload directly. I have modify columns and also I have change the type of data to don't have any issue to test the command to upload the data but I have always:

ERROR:  missing data for column "col9"

I am using to upload the few csv into psql the next command:

```
for i in {0..9}; do psql -h host -p 5432-d db_name -U postgres -c  "\COPY table_name FROM '/path/to/file/file-00$i.csv' CSV HEADER;"; done
```

I have created the table by:

```
CREATE TABLE ppm (
    col1 VARCHAR(50), 
    col2 VARCHAR(50), 
    col3 VARCHAR(50), 
    col4 VARCHAR(50), 
    col5 VARCHAR(50),  
    col6 VARCHAR(50), 
    col7 VARCHAR(50), 
    col8 VARCHAR(50),
    col9 VARCHAR(50)
);
```

I have found several error so I have been changing the data type from numeric, float .. to all varchar and also I change it when creating the csv, I have tried modifying the type of data in both but still having a lot of issues to load the huge dataset.

Maybe there is away to do it more straightforward or I am missing something.

Thanks

Comment: The CSV file seems to have too few columns. Please adf a sample that causes the error to the question.

Comment: you nail it! I have been going around it thinking about quality of data and how to add null values and some of the columns have been deleted thanks